# how can I keep track of the sequence change?

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I want to keep track of LO_SEQ_NO before and after it changes currently I am getting after the change. Is there any way I can keep track of the status change

```
loan_test$lse <-with(loan_test, as.integer(c(FALSE, LO_SEQ_NO[-length(LO_SEQ_NO)] - LO_SEQ_NO[-1]) !=0))
```

Getting out put as

```
"LO_SEQ_NO lse
   358      0
   478      1
   478      0
   478      0
   478      0
```

But I need output as

```
"LO_SEQ_NO     lse
       358      1
       478      1
       478      0
       478      0
       478      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try check both the `lag` and `lead` of the column:

```
df %>% mutate(
    lse = as.integer(
        LO_SEQ_NO != lag(LO_SEQ_NO, default=first(LO_SEQ_NO)) | 
        LO_SEQ_NO != lead(LO_SEQ_NO, default=last(LO_SEQ_NO))
    )
)

#  LO_SEQ_NO lse
#1       358   1
#2       478   1
#3       478   0
#4       478   0
#5       478   0
```